# Struct declaration in Golang

Tags: go, struct, syntax

Given Go is largely based on C, and structs in that language are defined like this:

```
struct Person{...}
```

Why do we have the extra word in Go?

```
type Person struct{...}
```

Why do we need to mention both type and struct? Seems a little verbose.

Comment: Its verbose to make it consistent.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: All kinds of types can be crated using the same syntax. `type <name> <definition>`, no matter whether you've got an `int`, a slice, a `struct` or a `interface` or whatever as definition.

Comment: Yup. They really should leave out both, type _and_ struct; that would be even _shorter_!

Answer (score 3):

All top-level statements in Go begin with a keyword indicating the type of declaration: `package`, `import`, `type`, `var`, `const`, or `func`, per the [Go specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec). As to *why* those decisions were made, you would need to ask those who made them, i.e. the Go maintainers.

Comment: Nitpick, but, per the language spec, `package whatever` is a [_clause_](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Package_clause), not a declaration.

Answer (score 2):

Because both type and struct are significant here. You are defining a type with a keyword type. Your type could be anything, all of the following are valid

```
type MyBool bool
type MyInt int
type StringList []string
type StringListPointer *StringList
```

And to define a type that contains more than one value, you use the struct keyword.

```
type MyStruct struct {
    x    MyInt
    y    StringList
    next *MyStruct
}
```

And you could, technically, have a struct without defining a type. This is not used very often, but it does have its use cases where you only intend to use a particular struct once. This is valid.

```
x := struct {
    Name  string
    Value int
}{"Hello World!", 10}
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", x)
```

Comment: Struct is possible without type keyword when using anonymous struct.

Comment: Ah! Didn't realize. This makes even more sense. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Unkeyed fields in struct literal. Tsk tsk...

Answer (score 0):

*Consistency*. The `type` keyword is used in all [type definitions](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_definitions), and a *defined type*'s [*underlying type*](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types) needs not be a struct. Example:

```
type Fahrenheit int
```

Why would the language's designers make an exception for structs in Go's syntax?